# Can't use % height calculated using CSS grid fr unit in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-grid

I'm trying to get the browser to calculate the height of an element using CSS Grid and `fr` unit, and then pass down that height using `%` unit so that I can get scroll working on a child element without setting height manually.

Below is a minimal example. It has a header with dynamic height, and I'm able to get scroll working inside the content area (`#scroll-container`) without setting a hardcoded height/using JavaScript in Chrome and Safari. But this does not work in firefox [[JSFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/z6gyuj9m/1).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#page {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

#content {
  background: hotpink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.sidebar {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

#content-table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px 0;
  background: orange;
}

div.column {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

#scroll-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <header id="header">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi assumenda, neque qui cum quas similique totam in quibusdam optio inventore vero explicabo dignissimos quaerat fugit. Placeat, autem voluptate praesentium ad ab alias, cumque, incidunt
    dolore fuga facere error labore molestias.
  </header>
  <section id="content">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <main>
      <div id="content-table">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column">
          <div id="scroll-container">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis similique atque est blanditiis fugit natus, facere reiciendis, aut quisquam libero. Incidunt et veritatis, obcaecati tenetur tempora iusto numquam nostrum excepturi atque rem fugit sed
            rerum molestias aliquid, beatae. Illo iure, ab sit accusamus quae, laborum soluta dicta a corporis in assumenda id maiores delectus quo quia deserunt consectetur recusandae, commodi saepe porro necessitatibus, optio qui. Ipsum repellat aut
            excepturi quasi, quos, aperiam culpa? Nesciunt neque ex, nihil nulla animi aut voluptatum nisi quisquam ad error voluptas, soluta quibusdam itaque, ipsum ullam cupiditate molestias officia repudiandae debitis repellendus inventore praesentium
            iste? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam velit temporibus omnis unde reiciendis quam culpa, quidem repudiandae minima explicabo quod sunt impedit vitae ipsum iusto ex assumenda aut eius voluptatem! Quidem accusantium
            debitis, soluta laudantium quae blanditiis accusamus dicta alias in tenetur. Reprehenderit distinctio similique, iste cumque nisi doloremque eaque unde corporis earum quia, aperiam dolor modi. Maiores reiciendis, officia neque esse! Odio repudiandae
            fugiat vero porro expedita deleniti, unde beatae, dignissimos eum, quibusdam dicta quae. Culpa, recusandae, aut! Eligendi, harum. Quam hic incidunt ex nobis natus eveniet atque, error omnis ullam nemo! Perspiciatis veniam numquam sapiente
            consequatur tempore.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </section>
</div>
```

This is how it looks in Chrome/Safari:

> [image]

How it works in firefox:

> [image]

Anybody know why this doesn't work in Firefox? Is this a known bug? Is there a cross browser solution for this?

Comment: Does the `#content-table` element have to be `display: table`? That may be causing the problem. Have you considered using `display: flex` or `display: grid` to lay out that section? I've seen table elements create problems inside flex and grid containers before.

Comment: @Michael_B I tried using flexbox: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/z6gyuj9m/7/) it gets scroll on `<main>` indicating that the height is not known for child elements in any browsers...

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky layout. Keep in mind that the `fr` unit should not be considered a length (like % or em). [It's not a length.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit) It's just a function to consume free space. So `1fr` can't be used to trigger an overflow condition, or in `calc()`, or wherever standard lengths are necessary.